# Should i use nil in ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I have read lot of articles but when i did practically i think i am missing out something.

I have an application in which i am setting a singleton object for module which presents over other view controller.This singleton object instantiating others child objects.After completing task i am **dismissing the controller** and setting nil to singleton object.But in instruments it is showing many objects created by my this module are still *alive*.

**My first question is**- is dismissing a controller deallocate all its child object or not? or i have to explicitly set it to nil.

My application is still running, when these objects get deallocate in future(they are not leaks as they are not shown by instrument leaks and have no retain cycles)or i have to force explicitly by setting them nil as i don't need them they are wasting memory.

Why these some of strong properties and two or three instance variables are still remaining when i have deallocated its super parent (i.e singelton object).

There are some more objects which are shown by instrument in object listing have name `<x06...>` or `malloc` which are allocated by my code methods.Should i worry about these object allocations?

Comment: You should clarify if you are talking about properties or instance variables.

Comment: @Till they are properties and two or three are instance variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> dismissing a controller deallocate all its child object or not?

Not intrinsically, no.  It depends.  An object is deallocated after there are no more strong references to it in your application.

So if, for example, you have a strong instance variable referencing your controller, dismissing it isn't going to result in deallocation because you still have a strong reference to it.  However if you set it to `nil` afterwards, and there are no other strong references to the object, *then* it will be deallocated.

On the other hand, if you don't have a strong reference to it in your code, the only strong reference to it is from the presenting view controller, so when that dismisses it, there will be no strong references to it in your application, so it will be deallocated after it is dismissed.

> Why these some of strong properties and two or three instance variables are still remaining when i have deallocated its super parent (i.e singelton object).

You are getting your terminology mixed up here.  There's no such thing as a "super parent".  There are superclasses and superviews, but it's not clear if you mean any of them.  If you have persistent objects that you can't get rid of, post the code you are using.

Comment: thanks for your response, by "super parent" i mean the containment relationship of properties and instance variable in which they define.Actually my all objects in this module are come from singleton object and they have no relationship with objects in my application but problem is they are not get dealloccated when i set this singelton object to nil.Do you have any idea why are they not deallocating?

Answer (score 2):

First question:
No it's just call release: reference count down by 1, but dealloc when reference count equals 0.

Just check who takes refs to objects that is living after dissmissing controller.

This controller have to take all references to all objects that will be deallocate with it, and only this controller, nobody more.

**About setting to nil in ARC.** Yes, this is a good practice.
For example all **outlets** automatically(when you drag it from IB to code with right button) are created as (nonatomic, weak). **Weak** - means, that it will be set to **nil** when object deallocated.

Also, about ARC, nils and others: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

Answer (score 1):

`is dismissing a controller deallocate all its child object or not? or i have to explicitly set it to nil.`

Yes it calls release. And after that assigning `nil` to them are merely a thing.

`nil` makes you sure that you are no longer pointing to any garbage after releasing your old object. Assigning a nil to an object or a NULL to a memory pointer are similar.

And `release`-ing does not mean that that memory will be available from that moment of time. If stays there for quite a time, and if OS fails to find sufficient memory than these `release`-d memory are taken by OS.